# Configuring USB token for a standalone JavaFX application

Tags: java, security, javafx, token, desktop-application

This question may be off-topic but anyway I could not find any appropriate solution on Google so I have coded a standalone JavaFX application using JDK 14 & OpenJFX 15-ea+3 and I want to make this application work only when a USB token is connected to the computer. Actually I have three questions:

Q1: How to put a key on a USB Flash Memory & make it unreadable?

Q2: Which kind of key should be placed on USB Flash Memory? It should be a specific file or something?

Q3: How to read the key from USB Flash Memory when JavaFX application is up?

Comment: the question is too complex to be answered in one post. in general, usb is an interface to which any device can be connected (not only mass-storage) and the actual implementation of such schemes is done with them (for example with a smart card)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a small library to detect USB storage devices on Java. It works on Windows, OSX and Linux. Take a look at: https://github.com/samuelcampos/usbdrivedetector